# Does deleting a ssb4 save takeaway DLC?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I want to make a new Super Smash Bros 4 save file. I have all the DLC besides mii costumes, will they be taken away ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

No, DLC will not be taken away. Your Nintendo account (associated with your WiiU or 3DS) will still have access to your purchases.

The save file just includes play time, challenges, stages, items and hidden character unlocks.

Answer (score 0):

DLC is almost always tied to accounts, not save files. Otherwise people would have to buy the same item multiple times if they had multiple saves.

Save files *do* usually hold unlocked statuses. For instance, some DLC is only attainable through some kind of in-game challenge or when you reach a certain point in the story. In these cases you will 'lose' the DLC only in that you will need to replay the game to get the DLC items back to your character.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your DLC will be deleted **BUT,** you can re-download it from the eShop.
Anything purchased can be easily re-downloaded, as long as it's available on the eShop.

If you're having troubles downloading it, try calling Nintendo. The support number is on the back of the game case.

Answer (score -1):

You will keep your DLC, in fact, right after you delete the save file, the DLC will come back like you just bought them.